# Cloudflare returns encoding error when uploading file to stream

Tags: javascript, fetch, cloudflare

My javascript is the following

```
function uploadvideo(){
    var input = document.getElementById('myFile')

    let video = new FormData()
    video.append('file', input.files[0])
    video.append("", "\\")

    fetch("https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/{AccountID}/stream", {
        video,
        headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer {Token}",
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        },
        method: "POST"
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data));
}
```

When the function is called, Cloudflare returns the following

```
main.js:17 {result: null, success: false, errors: Array(1), messages: null}errors: Array(1)0: code: 10004message: "Decoding Error"[[Prototype]]: Objectlength: 1[[Prototype]]: Array(0)messages: nullresult: nullsuccess: false[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Comment: Does the network console in your browser out to api.cloudflare.com say more? Usually with APIs like this, you'll see more detailed error messages from the actual network log response. Particularly like HTTP codes, etc.